# Changing font color of a CSS Class

Tags: css

I am creating a WordPress Site and would like to change the text color of a css class.

At the bottom of my page (Pflegepate.jaydonmay.de) you will see a contact form. beside of it is a contact box. Next to the icons, there is a text, which is white. The first line is black because I can use html tags there.

Do you have a clue how i can change its text color using css?

Greetings JD

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a style making all of those colors white with !important

```
.get_in_touch, .get_in_touch a, .get_in_touch h3, .get_in_touch ul, .infobox, 
.infobox a, .infobox h3, .infobox ul {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

You can at least remove .infobox a from that

Comment: hello very cool u found out, which file includes this code? greetings

Answer (score 0):

Hello no problem here is the code Odenwaldstr. 4,

```
65597 Hünfelden</font></span></li><li class="phone phone-1"><font color="black"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-phone"></i></span><p><a href="tel:064389250699">06438 9250699</a></p></font></li><li class="mail"><font color="black"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-mail"></i></span><p><font color:="" black=""><a href="mailto:info@pflegepate.de">info@pflegepate.de</a></font></p></font></li><li class="www"><font color="black"><span class="icon"><i class="icon-link"></i></span><p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.pflegepate.de">www.pflegepate.de</a></p></font></li></ul></div></div>
```